# Custom color does not stick

Tags: text, color-picker

I use a custom color for certain words on my web site.  Every time want to use that color I need to click the Text Color icon and Customize...  I then type in the RGB.  Problem:  It doesn't save that number or hex code.  I have to type it in every session.  Is there a way to save that custom color from one session to the next?
Thank you.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23183406/4156379

Answer (score 2):

To shorten your search the article points out that the suggested code is old and that you can now use this plug-in to define custom colors: [Central Color Palette](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kt-tinymce-color-grid/)

Comment: It's a nice plugin, but it does not save my custom color from session to session.

Comment: Bummer. I’m sorry my suggestion didn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the same color every time then add a piece of css to your site

ie

.keyword{color:#11c8de;}

then span your special word with `<span class="keyword">YOUR SPECIAL WORD</span>`

this offeres more flexibility if you want to change the color in the future all you change is your css and not every single word.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I do not think this will work.  I actually have two custom colors that I use.  Plus, I am not an HTML coder and just about always use the Visual editor.

Comment: if you want something a little easier you can use a plugin like 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-custom-styles/

add you specific styles for your 2 words and then you will be able to select the text you want to style and use the dropdown to edit them to the same style every time.

Without setting some sort of style unfortunately thiers no way for the system to remember any of your settings

Comment: I downloaded the plugin you suggested.  Restarted the WP dashboard. 
 Highlighted some text, put in the custom color and exited again.  When I came back, highlighted other text, used the dropdown for color and nothing was saved.

Comment: so you have added your custom formats to the extension and they appear in the dropdown?

Comment: It's become much easier to copy/paste than get this to work.  No big deal, but I think updating the plugin to save the custom color, would be best.  Not my call.  I also memorized my custom color hex - 353e84.  Thanks for your help.